# iMac stuck on 100 % progress bar

Tags: imac, startup, catalina

I have a serious problem with my 2017 iMac running macOS Catalina BETA.  After a normal reboot the iMac loaded until the bar reached 100%. Then for hours nothing happens, it just stays at 100%.

The things I tried:

- Boot in Safemode - still hangs on 100%, can’t access Safemode
- Reset NVRAM/PRAM - nothing happened
- Reset SMC - nothing happened
- Run First Aid on all disks - helped and discovered nothing
- Uninstalled Google Chrome update in terminal - nothing happened
- Tried to reinstall MacOS Catalina - not enough space on my disk
- Tried these commands: `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/caches/opendirectory` and `mv ./mbr_cache ./mbr_cache-old` - “no such file or directory”
- Tried to boot in startup manager - still hung on 100%
- Tried to run the Apple diagnostics - it said everything is fine
- Single user mode with commands like `mount-uw /` - command not found
- Let the iMac sit for a couple days - still hangs on 100%

And so on…
So, as you can see, I tried many things and nothing helped. Do you have a good solution or a advice/suggestion without erasing the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a very good triage step that I follow even after doing a very good job like you in trying to eliminate things (or hope for a quick fix)

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267 (always start with the basics)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156 (Which leads to general OS startup)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207019 (which is the detailed - just updated and boot fails process)

Why not start down that path and this evening make a good last backup so you can proceed where it says erase and start over?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 (The erase and start over process)

Comment: Thank you for your research bmike! After I tried so much I also came to the conclusion, that the best way would be just to get the backup on the drive and delete the buggy one (luckily I had a backup from like two months ago). Now everything works just fine and I didn’t lost really important data. The moral from this case is: do backups FREQUENTLY. Thanks allot for your help! Take care and best regards, Aaron